# Image cropping like facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, facebook, crop

For those that have been on facebook it allows you to upload an image to use as your avatar, and if that image is too large you can drag it around in a container to set the co-ordinates of the crop.

Can anyone Help me out to implement this functionality in c# ASP.NET

Comment: How far along have you gotten? Are you stuck on a specific problem, or are you looking for a place to start?

Comment: I want to move image at the background of fixed window..simple cropping I have implemented with Jcrop.

Answer (score 5):

Probably this will do the job for you

http://webcropimage.codeplex.com/

For writing your own image cropper, study the source code of that.

Comment: I have tried Jcrop.I dont want to move the resizable crop window.What I want is to move image in the background below the fixed cropping window to create thumbnail.(like facebook)

Answer (score 4):

This will be mostly client-side. You can take a look at something like [Jcrop](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/).

Comment: JCrop works very well, you can send the coordinates back to the server to do server side cropping as well.

Answer (score 0):

the best resource on this issue is here.

http://blog.mironabramson.com/blog/post/2009/04/Cropping-image-using-jQuery%2c-Jcrop-and-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It does not provide exactly what the question asks for but I think Image Resizer is something you should look at.

http://www.imageresizing.net/